# Do people say 有能力 <do something> or 有 <do something> 的能力

Tags: usage, syntax

I've always been a bit confused about the order of using 有能力 and I'm hoping someone can clarify. Do people say "有能力 `do something`" or "有 `do something` 的能力"?

For example, could I say "他没有能力写代码？”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,both is correct.but I think `他不会写代码` is more naturally.

Answer (score 5):

Both is correct. Yay!

Think "I'm ABLE to code." and "I HAVE THE ABILITY of coding."

Answer (score 2):

Yes. So you can say:

```
他(没)有能力写代码
他(没)有写代码的能力
```

Answer (score 0):

》Think "I'm ABLE to code." and "I HAVE THE ABILITY of coding."

This is great. Helps explain why and not just say both are correct.

有寫代碼的能力 = have coding ability
有能力寫代碼 = have ability to code

coding ability (adj noun)
ability to code (noun -to- verb)